# StaleElementReferenceException selenium webdriver python and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to get a screen to highlight all the elements of your HTML code like in the image below:

[image]

I'm using Selenium and PhantomJS. However when you run the code for certain web pages like Youtube, it throws the error `StaleElementReferenceException`. I thought of letting the code continue to execute by ignoring the error using a try - except block, but it ends up running for more than 6 minutes before delivering the screen. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1301, 744)
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
driver.save_screenshot("/path/")
image = Image.open("/samepath/")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('*')
for b in body:
   x1 = b.location['x']
   y1 = b.location['y']
   x2 = x1 + b.size['width']
   y2 = y1 + b.size['height']
   if x1 <= 0 or y1 <= 0 or x2 <= 0 or y2 <= 0:
      continue
   draw.rectangle([x1, y1, x2, y2], outline = 255)
```

Comment: Have you tried waiting a few seconds for the page to load before saving the screenshot and traversing the page's elements?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using `implicity_wait`, but still throwing the error, sometimes.

Comment: You could also try filtering using a `.isDisplayed()` check before trying to grab the element's location.